# LINQ Subquery Where Clause could not be translated

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ef-core-2.2

I am converting this query to linq in EF Core 2.2 but I could not find any correct way:

```
select r.*,v.* from Planning.RefineryUnitMonthDatas r
join Planning.RefineryUnitMonthDataValues v on r.Id = v.EntityId
    join(
        select EntityId, max(v.CreatedAt) CreatedAt from Planning.RefineryUnitMonthDatas r
        join Planning.RefineryUnitMonthDataValues v on r.Id = v.EntityId
        where RefineryUnitId = @refinery and Date / 100 = @date
        group by EntityId
    ) t on r.Id = t.EntityId
    where t.CreatedAt = v.CreatedAt
```

This is my linq:

```
 from s in db.RefineryUnitMonthDatas
 join v in db.RefineryUnitMonthDataValues on s.Id equals v.EntityId
 join r in (
      from r in db.RefineryUnitMonthDatas
      join v in db.RefineryUnitMonthDataValues on r.Id equals v.EntityId
      where r.RefineryUnitId == refinery  && r.Date / 100 == date
      group v by v.EntityId into g
      select new { g.Key, CreatedAt = g.Max(s => s.CreatedAt) }
 ) on s.Id equals r.Key
 where r.CreatedAt == v.CreatedAt
 select new { s, v }
```

This works correctly but has performance issue and the last Where clause is not translated to sql. It warns:

> The LINQ expression 'where ([r].CreatedAt == [v].CreatedAt)' could not
>   be translated and will be evaluated locally

Does Core 2.2 support where clause for subquery or I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be one of the (many) EFC 2.2 query translator bugs/defects/shortcomings. Works as expected in EFC 3.1.

From all the "query patterns" (as they call them), the only one working I was able to found is to push the predicate into `join` clause, e.g. replace

```
) on s.Id equals r.Key
where r.CreatedAt == v.CreatedAt
```

with something like

```
) on new { Key = s.Id, v.CreatedAt } equals new { r.Key, r.CreatedAt }
```

Of course the workaround works only for `==` comparisons which can be turned into *equi-join*.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I upgraded to Core 3.1 and checked, the Where caluse still does not work in EFC 3.1, but the  equi-join method is fixed in EFC 3.1

Comment: Hi @Zatkhahi, it works for me exactly the way I explained it. Of course I've tested in with what I think is similar query, since you didn't include your model classes. Unfortunately playing with EF Core query translation between EFC versions is really a trial and error approach, and has to be re-tested with every new version (they fix some things, but broke another things etc.). Note that in 3.x many things which in 2.x are inefficiencies caused by client evaluation are now runtime exceptions.